# Selenium and Internet Explorer Driver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, exception, selenium

I'm trying to run some tests with C# and InternetExplorerDriver.

This code is executed on Windows Server 2012, 64 bit.

Right after navigation to a new URL, I'm calling a function that waits until a page loads\20 seconds timeout.

```
private bool waitForPageToLoad()
    {
        try
        {
            int timeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeoutForCustomExpression"]);
            IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(m_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));

            wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)m_driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
        }
        catch//(Exception e) //timeout
        {
            log(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The function works great for every browser other than IE.

On IE, I the following error in my log:

> JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.PropagateExceptionIfNotIgnored(Exception
>   e) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver.Support\UI\DefaultWait.cs:line
>   222 at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2
>   condition) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver.Support\UI\DefaultWait.cs:line
>   180 at MainClass.waitForPageToLoad()

I have no idea why it happens.
Could somebody help me out here?

Sincerely,
Adam.

Comment: Log the whole exception, as in log `e.ToString()`, not just the message and concatenate the stack trace to it. What version of IE is this? Can you run that javascript on IE's Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all that extra information that Arran requested, it's hard to help you understand the error.
However if you're just looking for a quick fix that works in all browsers, I always just use 
    `Thread.sleep(int milliseconds);`
for my Selenium tests in C# that need to wait for a page to load or a certain element to render before continuing.